# Chicken Linear Dimensions

Tags: chicken, oven, roast

I just bought a 5 qt Lodge deep dutch oven and had luck roasting some vegetables in it on a grill, but now want to try a whole chicken.

I am curious if anyone knows the rough linear dimensions of a roasting chicken (Link - https://www.heb.com/product-detail/h-e-b-natural-nbsp-whole-nbsp-roasting-chicken-nbsp-avg-6-44-lbs/2231861) to know if it will fit in the 5 qt dutch oven or if I should get something bigger.

I am less worried about extra room, but more so if I can get the chicken in there without issues.

Worst case I could drive to the store and check, but I figured someone here may know from experience.

Comment: Do you have the linear dimensions of your container, too? That might be useful to add to the question.

Answer (score 3):

As chicken size will vary by weight and breed, there are no specific "linear dimensions" that apply to every chicken. Also, a chicken carcass may be manipulated to better fit a width or length.

A 5qt dutch oven can comfortably take a 1.5kg (3lb) chicken carcass, but it is highly unlikely that the linked 6.4lb chicken will fit into the 5qt dutch oven.

As you have the link to the company site that produces that 6.4lb chicken, perhaps you can contact them and ask them the size of their chickens. They should have a good idea as they need to fit them inside the packaging.

Answer (score 0):

He's looking for a rough dimension not specifics. I would guess a chicken is about 10 to 14 inches long or about the size of a small loaf of bread. Figure on about 2.5 quarts per person. I would guess that one chicken will feed about 4 to 5 people. I would get a 8 to 10 quart pot. I hope that helps.